# words amalgamation

Tags: python, string, list, character, combinations

I am new user learning python. I have query if it can be done or not. If user input a word suppose "Dance" and characters are "$" and "@", he would get a all possibilities of word and character combination for example ['D$@a$@n@$c@$e',D@$a@$n@$c@$e, 'Da$n$c$e', 'D$@an$c@$e', 'Da@nc$e'], etc. It should give a combinations. Is it possible to achieve?

```
import itertools as it

string = 'ABCD'  # input('enter string: ')
fill_char = '$'  # input('enter fill_char: ')

fillers = it.product(['', fill_char], repeat=len(string))

for filler in fillers:
    tmp = it.zip_longest(string, filler)
    print(''.join([''.join(char_and_fill_char) for char_and_fill_char in tmp]))


Output:
ABCD
ABCD$
ABC$D
ABC$D$
AB$CD
AB$CD$
AB$C$D
AB$C$D$
A$BCD
A$BCD$
A$BC$D
A$BC$D$
A$B$CD
A$B$CD$
A$B$C$D
A$B$C$D$
```

I wanted combination of 3 characters. If anybody could help I would be very greatful.

Comment: You can use len() to find the length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution:
For more clear presentation I only chose a string of two letters. Basically take every single letter of your `string` and join all possible combinations of `fill_chars` to it. Then build the product of all lists (each containing all combinations for one letter).
Added several comments and print statements for explanation.

```
from itertools import permutations, product
string = 'AB'  # input('enter string: ')
fill_char = '$@'  # input('enter fill_char: ')

s_lst = list(string)
fill_lst = list(fill_char)
powerSet = []

for char in s_lst:
    perm_each_char=[]
    
    for k in range(len(fill_char)+1):
        tmp = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(fill_lst, k)]
        # tmp : permutation result in list, each joined together to string (e.g k=2: ['@$', '$@'])
        tmp2 = [''.join((char,elem)) for elem in tmp]
        # tmp2 : list of current char joined with each item in list of tmp (e.g. k=2: ['A@$', 'A$@'])
        perm_each_char.extend(tmp2)
        print(f"{char=} - {k=} - {perm_each_char=}")
        
    powerSet.append(perm_each_char) # list of lists, each list contains all permutations of one char of the string
    print(f"combined: {powerSet=} \n")
    
all_combinations = list(''.join(x) for x in product(*powerSet))
# now you build the itertools.product with all lists to get every combination
print(f"{all_combinations=}")

Output:

char='A' - k=0 - perm_each_char=['A']
char='A' - k=1 - perm_each_char=['A', 'A$', 'A@']
char='A' - k=2 - perm_each_char=['A', 'A$', 'A@', 'A$@', 'A@$']
combined: powerSet=[['A', 'A$', 'A@', 'A$@', 'A@$']] 

char='B' - k=0 - perm_each_char=['B']
char='B' - k=1 - perm_each_char=['B', 'B$', 'B@']
char='B' - k=2 - perm_each_char=['B', 'B$', 'B@', 'B$@', 'B@$']
combined: powerSet=[['A', 'A$', 'A@', 'A$@', 'A@$'], ['B', 'B$', 'B@', 'B$@', 'B@$']] 

all_combinations=['AB', 'AB$', 'AB@', 'AB$@', 'AB@$', 'A$B', 'A$B$', 'A$B@', 'A$B$@', 'A$B@$', 'A@B', 'A@B$', 'A@B@', 'A@B$@', 'A@B@$', 'A$@B', 'A$@B$', 'A$@B@', 'A$@B$@', 'A$@B@$', 'A@$B', 'A@$B$', 'A@$B@', 'A@$B$@', 'A@$B@$']
```